# How to run this form in QTCreator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am following 'C++ GUI programming with QT 2ndEd'. I design a form using QTCreator 'Widget' template and save it as form.ui in a directory. Then I write main.cpp file in same directory. The 'Run' option is not enable still. The book says to run qmake to create .pro file and a makefile. How I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by the 'widget' template because it is not listed in my QTCreator options.

You should create a 'Qt Gui application' project in QTCreator, and then add that form.ui to your new project. With some code to create the form and show it you can build and run it.

[How to create a projectin Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-project-creating.html)

Comment: thank you. I know how to create a GUI Application that way & that include a .pro, main file etc by default. You can find the templates in QTCreator for form building by: new project->QT->QT Designer Form->Choose a form template. As here only form.ui & main.cpp is build following the book. qmake is some instruction to make a .pro file after that hopefully 'RUN' will be enable, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Creating a application project will automaticly create the setup for building against a specific target. So why not move you form into such an project? You have created a 'form' not a application with a 'form'.

Comment: Yeah, that's is very kool. Bec I am trying to follow all book examples. Actually I found from search now that 'qmake -project' is run on command prompt that creates .pro file which enable QTCreator to run the project. Though still not able to run qmake probably some path error. Thanks again for ur nice advice.

Comment: This is not a solution to the stated problem. The OP needs to add the form in the .pro file as `FORMS += form.ui` and run the qmake.

Comment: @CroCo: the user stated that he didn't have a project file (.pro). So he needs to create one first.

Comment: "*the user stated he didn't have  a project file ...*", so the solution is either the OP let qmake creates it as the author did or a project file needs to be created, therefore, opening Qt Creator is not a solution since the whole point of the author's perspective is how to use Qt Designer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late but I feel it is good to add some details regarding this issue. The whole point of the example stated in the book is to show you how to create applications without invoking Qt Creator. In your case, once you've done creating your form, you need to add it in the `.pro` file as follows:

```
FORMS += form.ui
```

This is because you are using your own `.pro` but the author lets `qmake` to create the `.pro`. The difference is that in your own project file, you can customize the file as you wish. This is why you need explicitly to add the form to `.pro`. If you are lazy, then let the qmake does the job as the author did.